# Is there any issues with Installing windows 10 on MD101 Macbook pro?

Tags: windows, mac, boot-camp

I want to install Windows 10 on my MD101 macbookpro, however the page below says that my machine is not among the macs that support Windows10.

[Mac computers that support Windows 10](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht204990)

My machines information is as follows:

> - macOS Sierra
> - version 10.12.6
> - MacBook Pro (13-inch, Late 2011)

I want to know if it can be installed on my machine? Is it compatible? In opinion, there is no reason to think it doesn't work on my machine. However, I want to make sure.

Comment: Are you asking if Windows 10 will support a 2011 Macbook Pro? You should read the article again, it only applies running Windows 10 with Boot Camp, your device is more then capable, provided you format your HDD and install Windows 10. However, drivers might be an issue, but that is a separate problem from the one you asked. It would be more your specifications for your device, that way we can refer you to the Windows 10 specification page, and your question is easily answered.

Comment: There will be no drivers. It will potentially work, but you'll lose functionality, bluetooth, wifi etc you may not be able to get going at all. Boot Camp will not allow you to do it, so before you even start you would need to make sure your intended USB boot key will actually work. You'd have more luck if you started with WIn7 or 8 & upgraded afterwards; at least then you would have rudimentary legacy support.

Comment: You don’t have to use Boot Camp.  Boot Camp is used to install Windows from within macOS to the device.  You can replace macOS if you want but the experience will be bad, and drivers will still be a problem, because the same drivers are used (which won’t exist because of the lack of support due to Boot Camp)

Answer (score 1):

As your Mac does not support installing Windows 10 via BootCamp, you can always install it with Parallels Desktop or Vmware Fusion. It won't be as much as fast as BootCamp, but it's suitable for most of the tasks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes.

It would be best to install using your optical drive. If this is not possible, then you can try using a USB method given [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308743/how-to-install-windows-10-into-a-2011-imac-without-using-the-boot-camp-assistant/308812#308812).

You should use the Boot Camp Assistant to download the Windows Support Software. You can also directly download the drivers for your Mac from the web site: [Boot Camp Support Software 5.1.5621](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1720?locale=en_US). These files will need to be transferred to a "MS-DOS (FAT)" formatted flash drive.

If the Boot Camp Assistant will not aid in the installation of Windows then you will have to do this manually. The basic steps are given below.

1. You need to have a "MS-DOS (FAT)" formatted flash drive containing the Windows Support Software.
2. You need to create a "MS-DOS (FAT)" formatted volume in either the 2nd, 3rd or 4th partition on your primary internal drive (`disk0`). Label the volume "BOOTCAMP".
3. You need to make sure the primary drive is using the hybrid GPT/MBR partitioning scheme. See the answer to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308824/how-to-convert-a-drive-from-the-gpt-format-to-the-hybrid-gpt-mbr-format-when-usi).
4. Insert the DVD, restart the Mac, hold down the option until the Startup Manager appears.
5. Select the DVD icon labeled "Windows".
6. When asked, choose "Custom: Install Windows only (advanced)".
7. Install Windows to the "BOOTCAMP" volume after selecting to format the volume.
8. When the Mac reboots to macOS, goto "System Preferences" to select Windows as the startup disk. Restart the Mac so Windows can finish installing.
9. After installation completes, install the Windows Support Software. Basically, run the setup application found in the "BootCamp" folder on the USB flash drive.